# XeLaTeX and changing fonts inside a document

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Here is a detailed explanation of how to use various fonts inside a document in `XeLaTeX`: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/37251#37251)

However, there is no MWE to illustrate this. Say I would like to create a single document whose main font is `ebgaramond`, but inside this document, I want various flowery texts set in, for example, Deutsche Normalschrift (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/deutschenormalscrift/), or some other font, maybe ten other fonts in the same document.

How can I accomplish this? My request is, a MWE of at least three different fonts (say ebgaramond, Deutsche Normalschrift and Bitstream Charter) which accomplishes this. Is this possible in any case? You may complete the following code if you like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    %All this is set in EBGaramond.
    \lipsum[1-8]
    % %Upto this.
    \setingaudyfont{Very long text, maybe.}
    %Again set in EBGaramond. etc etc.

\end{document}
```

==============Edit===================

Here is what I get when I do this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\deutschenormalscript{URW Chancery L}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    %All this is set in EBGaramond.
    \lipsum[1-8]
    % %Upto this.
    {\fontspec{Bitstream Charter} \lipsum[5]}
    %Again set in EBGaramond. etc etc.


    {\deutschenormalscript \lipsum[6]}


\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Various font problems]

Comment: I don’t understand what you don’t understand about the post you linked to.  It is very detailed, just read it.  The parts you need most are the sections “selecting font locally” and “restricting the scope of the selection”: just define a new font with `\newfontfamily\deutschenormalscript{Deutsche Normalschrift` and type `{\deutschenormalschrift Text in Deutsch Normalschrift}`.

Comment: `@Arthur Reutenauer`, please see the update. And moreover, it is very difficult to know what name to choose, is it `ebgaramond` or `EB Garamond`? etc. Only one of them is correct. How do I see the list of font names? The explanation given in the link above does not work.

Comment: I think Bitstream Charter is a Type1 font.
Unfortunately Type1 font as a native font
in xdvipdfmx was implemented by Jiang Jiang
a little after the release of TL 2015.
If you build xdvipdfmx by using the current sources
in the TeX Live repository, you will obtain
expected results.

Comment: `@Akira Kakuto`, another problem is that, it is difficult to find the system font names. For example, we cannot use `ebgaramond`; we have to use `EB Garamond` and so on. How can I see the right font names in my system? I am on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: The problem shown in the screenshot has nothing to do with the use of multiple fonts: you can reproduce just using Bitstream Charter. So it is a font-specific problem. Even if it is using type1, I don't think it should be doing this. Plus the type of font I get seems to be the same for EB Garamond. Your other question: I always use `otfinfo -i <path to font>` for getting the name and `otfinfo` also has options for getting lists of supported scripts and features.

Comment: It is nont font specific problem, other fonts show similar problems, as updated.

Comment: The latest sources of xdvipdfmx in the TeX Live repository
contain still bugs for native type1 fonts. I hope that
experts will fix xdvipdfmx and/or xetex in the near future.